# How can I get data from a column in an ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to get the data from a column in a pipeline to loop through it.

I have tried with a script putting the query to get the data from the SQL server to loop through the data that is in that column, but it returns the query data in an array of arrays in json.

Comment: If the output required is not to be in array of array, **what is the required  output format?**

Comment: Are you reading the data from SQL already? Can you show what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Lookup Activity to Query your database (Any RDBMS, but in my example an Azure SQL Database). The below screenshot shows you how to configure your Lookup Activity

[image: Lookup Activity]

Next, use a For Each activity to iterate over the Output of your Lookup Activity. The below screenshot shows you how to configure the settings of your For Each Activity

[image: For Each Activity]

Finally, You are now ready to reference any of the columns from your Lookup activity in an iterative fashion. This is the part where you put the activities you want to run within the For Each. See screenshot below for how to reference a column value from your output.

[image: Activities Within For Each]

Comment: Feel free to grab me on Teams or Zoom.

Comment: Using the lookup, these are the output data from the lookup {
 "count": 3,
 "value": [
  {
   "nombre": "dani"
  },
  {
   "nombre": "juan"
  },
  {
   "nombre": "lucia"
  }
 ], When using the for each, this is the error. 
The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.

Comment: What type of RDBMS (Database) asre you pulling from? If it's SQL Server, then I would suggest doing some JSON shredding so that instead of a JSON array, you have Nombre as a column, with "dani", "juan", "lucia" as row values within the Nombre column